# Multiplying/dividing issue

Tags: delphi, integer, division, multiplication

I am trying to write a program which will do multiply/divide the same variable without it resetting(sorry if it is not explained well). I will show an example if what I want

```
var
selection:integer

writeln ('Select a number');
readln (selection);
writeln (selection*10);
writeln (selection/5);
```

What I want to happen is for the selection variable to be multiplied by 10, then divided by 5. e.g. if the user enters 5, it will be multiplied by 10, then divided by 5. So I should get 5*10=50, then 50/5=10. But instead it will do 5*10, and then 5/5 separately.How would I do it so that it does the multiplication, and then the division to the new number made from the multiplication?

Comment: Are you talking about this: `selection := selection * 10; selection := selection div 5;` ?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't modifying the variable. You need to write it like this:

```
selection := selection * 10;
writeln(selection);
selection := selection div 5;
writeln(selection);
```

Note also that you need to use integer division, `div`, rather than real division, `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I forgot to mention in the OP,but I am working with a real variable

Comment: Er, no. It's an integer. Right there in the question. But it doesn't change much. If you want real division use `/`.

Comment: I am working with a real variable, I just commented that that I forgot to put that it is a real variable.

Comment: What matters is the question that you asked. That's all I can see. As I said the issue is independent off the type.